# Issues installing Ubuntu server onto old PC

Tags: boot, server, system-installation

I have an old gaming PC that I put into a server case and I am currently trying to install Ubuntu server onto it. I have a 250 gb ssd I wiped it on windows using `diskpart clean` and then connected it to my server to be.

I then downloaded Ubuntu server and used PowerISO to create a bootable usb drive.

I go through the installation process for the server I input my username password and server name, it gets to `installing kernal` and then it says installation failed:

So it gets to:

Configuring pollinate user-agent on target-system

and then it fails

```
curtin.util.ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command:
['sh', '-c', 'exec "$0" "$@" 2>&1', 'install-grub', '/target', '/dev/sda']
Exit code: 1
Reason: -
```

Some key lines that I see are

`Failed to connect to lvmetas. Falling back to device scanning. grub-probe: error: cannot find GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1. Check your device.map.`

and

`/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: directory is encrypted`

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? If UEFI, do you have ESP? If BIOS is drive gpt partitioned? If gpt you need a bios_grub partition. Was drive ever part of RAID configuration? It may have RAID meta-data left on it, which you must remove.

Comment: The drive was never used as raid and it comes from a windows PC i completely formatted it or at least it think I did with diskpart on windows BIOS install since people keep telling me not disable secure boot

Comment: If over 5 years old, it will be BIOS only, and then if not UEFI it cannot have UEFI Secure Boot. Just to see how far your install went. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I switched out the motherboard to another and the installation worked. I want to say the problem is solved but I'm gonna guess it's just a hardware incompatibility issue maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the motherboard, the motherboard was that did not work was a `Gigabyte 970A-UD3` I changed it to another Asus gaming mother board and the installation went by perfectly!